# Accessing name value of an array

Tags: php, database, laravel, forms, foreach

my first post here, and first proper Laravel project.

I have a table, from which I am pulling out at random 3 values. Each of those contain an (1) action, that I am printing, and a (2) number of points associated with this action. The table currently does not have any more rows.

Each of the actions when displaying is now assigned a checkbox, which user can tick (or not) before submitting the form. Currently it looks like this:

```
@foreach (App\Models\Action::randomiser() AS $action)
                  <label class="container"><sup>{{ $action->action }}</sup>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="{{ $action->point }}">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
     @endforeach
```

The trouble is,  I need to collect the values of each ticked box. Now, the method is POST, but the there is no table of reference for it - you tick the boxes, and submit, and output comes back, or at least it COULD come back if I could access the value of the action.

When I've done it in similar fashion, but without using foreach, and I could access value quite easily, and all of it added nicely together:

```
$total = (
    +(isset($_POST["action[1]"]) ? ($_POST["action[1]"]): 0) + 
    +(isset($_POST["action[2]"]) ? ($_POST["action[2]"]): 0) +
    +(isset($_POST["action[0]"]) ? ($_POST["action[0]"]): 0));
```

then $total gets evaluated in next function.

I tried to access it via each item in an array, using `+(isset($_POST["action[0]"])` etc, but that comes back with 0 no matter how many items I tick in .

Is there some smart way to access these values? Or if that's impossible, can you perhaps suggest best way to create the table to collect the information? I will need to pull foreign key of $action->point, and each value would have to count as boolean (true or not true)...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$_POST["action[1]"]` doesn't seem right. It should be `$_POST["action"][1]`. Or, inside a loop `$_POST["action"][$i]`, assuming `$i` is the current index of the loop.

Comment: If you are ever unsure what information you are getting back - try dumping out `$_POST` to see what the structure of the data is.

Comment: El_Vanya - that's exactly what I needed, I am very grateful for your help!